# phpUnderControl and CodeBrowser

Tags: php, phpunit, phpundercontrol, php-codebrowser

Does phpUnderControl have a built in code browser? If so, how do I change it to use PHP_CodeBrowser instead?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it has. What you need to do is to include phpcb (PHP_CodeBrowser) on your build process and have CruiseControl's artifacts publisher copies the result into your artifacts' folder.

> <execute command="phpcb --log projects/${project.name}/build/logs --source projects/${project.name}/source/PHP --output projects/${project.name}/build/php-code-browser"/>
>
> <artifactspublisher dir="projects/${project.name}/build/php-code-browser" dest="artifacts/${project.name}" subdirectory="php-code-browser"/>

Or alternatively, you may create a symbolic from artifacts folder pointing to phpcb's output directory.

e.g. `ln -s /PATH/TO/PHPCB/OUTPUT/DIR/php-code-browser /PATH_TO_CRUISECONTROL/artifacts/PROJECT_NAME/LATEST_LOG/php-code-browser`

Answer (score 2):

I have not integrated those myself yet, but here are two links I bookmarked a while ago that could interest you :

- [**PHP_CodeBrowser Release version 0.1.0**](http://blog.thinkphp.de/archives/464-PHP_CodeBrowser-Release-version-0.1.0.html) : at the end of the article, it says "*For the integration in cruisecontrol, please have a look at the README file, or use the current version of phpUnderControl*"
- And [**phpUnderControl 0.5.0 released**](http://manuel-pichler.de/archives/69-phpUnderControl-0.5.0-released.html) gives some XML code that's needed to integrate PHP_CodeBrowser in phpUnderControl.